# Filling the polygons in shp file by using colors in basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, polygons

I have created a point map and overlayed county boundaries on it using python basemap. I have another shapefile which is based on species distribution map of IUCN data(species_13143). I have overlayed that shape file onto the previous map. It worked well. But unfortunately, it didn't fill up the polygons associated with it. I want to fill those polygons by using colors as per this map (I don't mind about colors; single color is ok)

[image: this map] .

I have found the similar question in StackOverflow. But none of that worked in my case. code and relevant image attached here..
[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
map = Basemap(projection = 'merc',  resolution = 'h',area_thresh = 0.5, llcrnrlon=79.2643, llcrnrlat=5.3135, urcrnrlon=82.0658, urcrnrlat=9.951)
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
map.fillcontinents(alpha=0.5)
map.drawmapboundary()
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 0.5), labels=[False, False, False, True], linewidth=0.1,)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 0.5), labels=[False, True, False, False], linewidth=0.1)
#Read district boundaries.
sh_info=map.readshapefile('C:\\Users\\Tharindu\\Downloads\\species_13143\\species_13143',"areas",color='blue')
shp_info = map.readshapefile('C:\\Users\\Tharindu\\downloads\\Compressed\\LKA_adm1',"areas")
for index,row in sightings_dropped.iterrows():
    x,y = map(row['longitude'], row['latitude'])
    map.plot(x, y, 'green', markersize=7, alpha=0.8,marker='o',markeredgecolor='black')
map.drawmapscale(81.5, 5.8, 80.5, 6, 50)
```

Comment: put an image  of what your output should look like...by manually painting, the link does't exaplain it.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question, thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is `sightings_dropped`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly... In essence, all you're looking for is just to fill in a shapefile with whatever color? This is actually listed in the basemap [docs](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html).

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

patches   = []

for info, shape in zip(map.comarques_info, map.comarques):
    patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= 'm', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2))
```

I'm a fan of list comprehension:

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

patches = [Polygon(np.array(shape), True) for info, shape in zip(m.states_info, m.states)]
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= 'green', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2))
```

Hopefully this helps and I answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon Molyneaux, it worked well. I was stuck on this as I am a beginner for basemap.. Thanks again :)

Comment: how to obtain states_info from hapefile. My shapefile says dont recognize states_info?